# error C2955: 'ListRemake' : use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

```
template <class T>
class ListRemake
{
    ...
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const ListRemake& obj);
};

template <class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const ListRemake& obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; i++)
        out << obj[i] << '\n';
    return out;
}
```

Gives the error C2955: 'ListRemake' : use of class template requires template argument list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const ListRemake& obj)
```

with

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const ListRemake<T>& obj)
```

Comment: I get a linker error: unresolved error: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class ListRemake<double> const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$ListRemake@N@@@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: @cable: Are you trying to separate declarations and definitions in different files? That doesn't work with templates.

Comment: no it's all in the same file with main() I pasted the whole code on pastebin if you want to take a look http://pastebin.com/E9VkcDNH

Comment: @cable you miss a "template<typename T>" for your friend declaration... Otherwise it declares a nontemplate function...

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `ListRemake` is a template and therefore you need to instantiate it to use it as a type (what you are doing in the `<<` operator).

Comment: I'm not sure i'm understanding. What am I doing wrong, what should I change?